# Potential SSH security problem?

Tags: security, ssh, freebsd

I just did a 'netstat -a' on my FreeBSD machine. I discovered the following:

```
Active Internet connections (including servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address Foreign Address (state)
tcp4 0 40 turban.ssh host90.embarqser.60230 ESTABLISHED
tcp4 0 0 turban.ssh host90.embarqser.59985 LAST_ACK
tcp4 0 0 turban.ssh host90.embarqser.47224 TIME_WAIT
tcp4 0 0 turban.ssh host90.embarqser.9304 LAST_ACK
```

Could there be someone intruding my machine? My hostname is 'turban' as you can see. I'm really 'new' about system security. Could someone enlighten me?

From `/var/log/auth.log`, a lot of errors like:

> May 4 20:07:10 turban sshd[47801]: Failed keyboard-interactive/pam for invalid user backup from 76.7.43.90 port 11831 ssh2
>
> May 4 20:07:13 turban sshd[47804]: error: PAM: authentication error for bin from 76.7.43.90...

Comment: a `netstat -an` is better, gives IP addresses instead of names.

Comment: Hi i did a netstat -an as you suggested. This is what I found out. http://dawhois.com/traceroute/?query=76.7.43.90 host90.embarqservices.net is connecting to my machine! This is an IP from USA. Really weird!

Comment: It's hard to know whether you have a problem from the information posted. Did you connect to anyone through ssh? Are you running a sshd? Do you allow anyone to connect from outside? What is the output of last (1)? What is the out put of w (1)? What processes are revealed by (for instance) "ps aux"?

Comment: last and w yield IPs which I can recognize. Probably someone is trying to log in my machine.

Comment: Not exactly what you're looking for, but perhaps still a good read: http://superuser.com/questions/244214/what-are-possible-security-issues-with-an-ssh-daemon/244234#244234

Answer (score 2):

Look at /var/auth.log for more information.

If someone is trying to access to your machine is loged in this file.

Example from my auth.log:

> Apr 24 13:53:16 my-server sshd[8107]: Failed password for invalid user db2 from 123.123.123.123 port 59167 ssh2

To see IP of connected (SSH connections) users type this:

```
netstat -atn | egrep '(:22)' | egrep -v '(:::|0.0.0.0)' | awk '{print substr($5,0,length($5)-5)}' | sort | uniq -c
```

This will show you IP and number of connection/IP

Comment: From /var/log/auth.log, a lot of errors like what I pasted below.

Comment: May  4 20:07:10 turban sshd[47801]: Failed keyboard-interactive/pam for invalid user backup from 76.7.43.90 port 11831 ssh2
May  4 20:07:13 turban sshd[47804]: error: PAM: authentication error for bin from 76.7.43.90

Comment: @Will, you should keep updating your question with data your are posting as comments here -- it will help others to quickly grasp your problem statement.

Answer (score 1):

I would not worry too much about this specific discovery. Maybe somebody did try to "<del>port-knock</del> port-scan" on your SSH-port (e.g. with a dictionary scanner), but didn't succeed since you hopefully have a proper password or auth-key only.

To brighten your knowledge, read this blogpost [Improve SSH Remote Access Security](http://polach.cc/improve-ssh-remote-access-security) to 
see what else you can do, esp. the part "Allow Only Specific User to Log In by SSH".
And **do not allow** root logins through SSH!

Comment: I guess you refer to the term "`port-scan`". The term "`port-knock`" has a very different meaning (http://www.portknocking.org/ would be an interesting read).

Comment: @nik You're completely right! Changed the text (and also looking into Knock (http://www.zeroflux.org/projects/knock) now. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is that someone is trying to break into your system, most likely via a variation on the typical dictionary attack (i.e. by trying common username/password combinations, instead of just randomly guessing).

In addition to the excellent advice from @Henk (I create a specific group, usually `sshusers`, and only permit users in that group to log in, for example), I would suggest installing [Fail2ban](http://www.fail2ban.org/wiki/index.php/Main_Page) on your system with an SSH jail set up. This will elevate the difficulty of a brute-force attack against your server to the realm of nigh impossibility, since attackers will find themselves suddenly shut off for a period of time when they try; combine this with the how-to entitled [Fail2ban monitoring Fail2ban](http://whyscream.net/wiki/index.php/Fail2ban_monitoring_Fail2ban) to create an elevated response to an attack (mine's set up with the default 10 minute ban initially, and then a full week if they're persistent), and you can just stop worrying altogether (provided you have at least adequately strong passwords; use pubkeys instead and you're all but invincible!).

Answer (score 1):

My logs are full of russians, americans trying English names on my 22nd port. Too bad for them I moved SSH port to 307, and I use port-knocking on port 54321 to open the SSH port.